# Is it possible to user native pin code/ pattern to login a remote system?

Tags: android, security, authentication, pin-code, fido-u2f

I am designing an android app where I can login in multiple ways: *password, pin code, pattern, fingerprint..*

While password login implementation is easy, the server will check against the password, authenticate the user and manage the login session.

> when come to pin code login, it seems complicated.As far as I know, pin code is some kind of **"native authentication"**, the "checking process" happens within the device, or the android system. **How can the app login to the server if the app dosen't sent any credential to server even the "native authentication" succeed?**

- Obviously, I don't want a solution that map a pincode/pattern to some "password" in the server, because that's no different from password login.
- Another solution is storing some credentials(token,password,cert) on device,and forward to server after "native authentication".But I think this is unsafe.

so, how can the app connect these "native authentication"(pin code, pattern, fingerpring) with the remote server, in order to be trusted by the server?

Thanks.

---

supplement: as for the fingerprint login, I refer to the FIDO UAF.This solution deals with my problem:after a "native authentication", the fido client will send back some "assertion data" to server, and the server can verify the fido client against these data, and accept the assertion.

Comment: Is the server side implemented by you? If yes, you can simple send a flag to server upon successful native authentication on the device. So, the server can trust that device.

Comment: @Prerak Sola : I can do this, but the web api I use to send flag would be exposed, which is a security risk, yes? I'm considering a solution that the client can speak to the server "this is a legal user" and the server in someway can veriy the client a legal client so that what he said is credible.

Comment: How will it be exposed? Instead of sending username and password, you'll be sending some third value.

Comment: @PrerakSola this "third value" will be verified by the server and authenticate succeed.The problem is how to generate this "third value" and where to store it? If a legal "third value" is easy to generate, then this api is unsafe; if it's complicated to generate and stored on device, it is still unsafe because it's there on the device.  But your suggestion reminds me the private/public key solution.How to stored the private key is the main concern now.